# Python re.search assistance for Django

Tags: python, regex, django-views

I need to replace part of an an html string via a Django custom template tag that I am customising.

The string in it's raw format is as follows:

```
arg = "<a class='login-password-forget' tabindex='1' href='{% url 'account:pwdreset'%}'>Forgot your password?</a>"
```

I need to replace the `{% url 'account:pwdreset'%}` part with a url string using re.search().

The code that I written is clumsy and I would appreciate help with finding a better way of achieving the same.

```
url_string = re.search("{.*?}", arg)
url_string_inner = re.search("'(.+?)'", url_string.group())

add_html = SafeText(''.join([arg.split('{')[0], reverse(url_string_inner.group(1)), arg.split('}')[1]]))
```

!!UPDATE!!
The solution that I ran with is as follows:

```
    url_string = re.search("{.*?}", arg)
    url_string_inner = re.search("'(.+?)'", url_string.group())
    add_html = SafeText(''.join([arg.split('{')[0], reverse(url_string_inner.group(1)), arg.split('}')[1]]))
```

Thank you Fourth Bird for your help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with python, but it seems to me like the regex is fine, but you're missing a single quote in your href code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to replace the the part with `'account:pwdreset'` you could use re.sub with a capture group and use that group in the replacement between single quotes

```
'{%\s*url '([^']*)'%}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z5hMQp/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/FLnn6Z)

```py
import re

pattern = r"'{%\s*url '([^']*)'%}"
s = "<a class='login-password-forget' tabindex='1' href='{% url 'account:pwdreset'%}>Forgot your password?</a>"
print(re.sub(pattern, r"'\1'", s))
```

Output

```html
<a class='login-password-forget' tabindex='1' href=account:pwdreset>Forgot your password?</a>
```